# Disk usage problem, don't know why my disk is full (Googe Cloud, Windows Server 2016)

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a strange problem when using a Google Cloud Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Instance.

Sum all files and folders size in C: are 19.8GB,

[image: Sum all files and folders size]

but C: drive properties show that used 48.2GB.

[image: C drive usage]

I have only 1 drive, so where is disk space ?

Updated:

Delete log in folder C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 solved problem, but I don't know why Windows does not calculate it's size ?

Comment: 1) Has the system ever crashed? Under "Tools" run a "Check". Enable the option to repair during reboot. 2) Do you have VSS enabled? VSS Snapshots consume space. `vssadmin list shadows` and `vssadmin list shadowstorage`. 3) Check for System Restore Points

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/questions/1151844/how-to-toggle-show-hide-hidden-files-in-windows-through-command-line

Answer (score 0):

In my case similar result was caused by Windows' path length limit of 256 characters. Docker created files with longer paths which were not showing up in explorer until I disabled the file path length limit in the registry.